# How to make range section attribute "specific-use" value - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am trying to numbers range section attribute `specific-use` in single para element. I am fetching single value `<span style="case">` with `group-by` and fetching the value `group-by="ancestor::sec[1]"`. Is it possible make range when comes `<span style="case">` value continue `descendant::` or `following-sibling::` then can we fetch last `specific-use` value.
**Input XML**

```
<book>
<sec disp-level="1" specific-use="1">
    <p>aaaaaa</p>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="2">
        <p><span style="case">super</span></p>
    </sec>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="3">
        <blockquote>
        <p><span style="case">super</span></p>
        </blockquote>
    </sec>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="4">
            <p><span style="case">super</span></p>
    </sec>
</sec>
<sec disp-level="1" specific-use="5">
    <p><span style="case">super</span>, <span style="case">active</span></p>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="6">
        <p><span style="case">active</span></p>
    </sec>
</sec>
<sec disp-level="1" specific-use="7">
    <p><span style="case">active</span></p>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="8">
        <p><span style="case">active</span></p>
    </sec>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="9">
        <p><span style="case">super</span></p>
    </sec>
    <sec disp-level="2" specific-use="10">
        <p><span style="case">active</span></p>
    </sec>
</sec>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
      <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//*" group-by="span[@style='case']">
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <p>
                <case><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></case><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <sec>
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <number>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::sec[1]/@specific-use"/>
                </number>
                  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                  </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </sec>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**My XSLT given output** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/7

**My Expected Output**

```
<book>
<p><case>super</case> <sec><number>2</number>&#x2013;<number>4</number>, <number>5</number>, <number>9</number></sec></p>
<p><case>active</case> <sec><number>5</number>&#x2013;<number>8</number>, <number>10</number></sec></p>
</book>
```

**For Example:**

super 2–4, 5, 9

active 5–8, 10

`2–4` : Create range Because `<span style="case">super</span>` search continued same value `child::` or `following-sibling::`.
`5–8` : Create range Because `<span style="case">active</span>` search continued same value `child::` or `following-sibling::`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the nested grouping is doing, to give you an example of identifying ranges in sequences of integer numbers, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/6 which just uses `group-adjacent=". - position()"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Thanks for the reply but `5` s/b not come range because the `<span style="case">super</span>` is come `disp-level="1"` and not `<span style="case">super</span>` `preceding-sibling::` sec `disp-level="1"` if `<span style="case">super</span>` come sec[1] then my expecting range `1–5`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the sample I linked to does not create the output you want, it processes the result of the sample you linked to, so perhaps you can adjust your grouping code to only wrap/group the elements you later want to check and concatenate as a range. I am afraid, as with your previous examples, I have not managed to understand from your description and your code snippets which criteria you want to implement exactly.

Comment: Sir, I want to make range only when this element value current position `<span style="case">super</span>` same search as continue `descendant::` and `following-sibling::`  sec then can we create range?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, Is it possible XSLT 3.0?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve, so whether I use XSLT 2 or 3, I can't implement what I haven't understood.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, I have edited more information. Please check.